# KDE Dolphin Folder Already Exists "Write Into" prompt default

Tags: kde, plasma, dolphin

I generally find KDE Plasma enjoyable to use, with one exception.  If you copy files and a folder with the same name exists in the destination it prompts.  I have search for a setting to change the behavior but have been unable to find one.

Is there a way to set a default so it always does a "Write Into" instead of interrupting?

[image]

Comment: My advice the default choice "Rename" instead "Write Into" is a form of protect of lost data  to the basic / new user

Comment: Not everybody is a new user.  Current behavior is fine by default but slows me down.

Comment: did you found a solution?